# RSS link from blogger doesn't works

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm developping a rss reader application following this tutorial http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/ . But when I put a blogger RSS link (like this http://blogname.com.br/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss) it does not work. Other links with this formart www.site.com/index.php?format=feed&type=rss works perfectlly. Which can be the problem?
Bellow follow the parser class.

```
public class DOMParser {

private RSSFeed feed = new RSSFeed();

public RSSFeed parseXML(String xml) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(xml);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        //Criar as instâncias necessárias
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
        dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        //Passa o xml
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //Pega todas as tags
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        int length = nl.getLength();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
            RSSItem item = new RSSItem();

            NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
            int clength = nchild.getLength();

            //Pegar os elementos requeridos de cada item
            for (int j = 1; j < clength; j = j + 2) {

                Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                String theString = null;
                String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                if (theString != null) {
                    if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                        // O valor do nó é "title", então devemos "setar"
                        // o valor do titulo de RSSItem
                        item.setTitle(theString);
                    } else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
                        item.setDescription(theString);                         
                        //Passa a descrição html para getar a url da imagem

                        String html = theString;
                        org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup
                                .parse(html);
                        Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                        item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));


                    } else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {
                        // We replace the plus and zero's in the date with
                        // empty string
                        String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000","");
                        item.setDate(formatedDate);
                    }
                }                   
            }
            //adiciona elemento a lista
            feed.addItem(item);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    //Retorna um objeto de RSSFeed, depois que todos os elementos foram adicionados a lista
    return feed;
}

}
```

Thanks a lot, and sorry by the very bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up the blog url.

```
 Unkown host: blogname.com.br
```

Comment: I tried to parse this URL. You should add a valid example. It would be easier to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh, okay. This http://www.augustourgente.com.br/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss is a link which doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry it is mainly in DOM parsing, never try that. Is it reach the jsoup part? Maybe I can help from then. Could you try it from a Java application? It is easier to debug from plain Java.

Comment: Thank for the help. In my search I find anything linking this error to the 'formmating'(informations in the same line, for example) of the xml. So, what I do to identing a xml file that I receiver on parser class?

Comment: I'm have a few experience. I already solve the problem of indentation, but this don't solves the problem.